# DC.js Ordering with filters

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, reductio

Hi I am ordering the x values in my bar chart with .ordering. It orders correctly. However on filtering on other linked charts the ordering doesn't change. How do I achieve this behaviour?

Also ordering for me only works when I am overriding the default `groupX.all()` function with

```
groupX.all = function() {
  return groupX.top(Infinity);
}
```

How can I make my bar chart order itself everytime it's redrawn?

Comment: I have no idea about the `all` override, seems like it should work without that.

Comment: I am now using 2.0.0-beta.27 version. It works without the override. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (untested):

```
chart.on('preRedraw', function() {
    chart.rescale();
});
```

Since the ordering is implemented via the X scale, this should get the chart to recompute the scale each time.

Comment: Do you mean that this didn't help but upgrading fixed it?

Comment: I meant the initial sort works without the override. The sort on filter still doesn't work.